# Host 'yang' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Tags: mysql-workbench, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to connect Power BI with MySQL workbench but every time I get this error "Details: "MySQL: Host 'yang' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

my server name is Yang, i have tried using the 127.1.... and inputting the database name, the server is running but I still get the same error every time on power bi

I can't connect Power BI with MySQL workbench to load my data

I have tried changing the privilege